# RecyclerView for Messages with Attachments not properly showing attachments

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a `MessageAdapter` that extends `RecyclerView.Adapter` for messages. This is what it should *look* like when it works properly. You click the Card and it expands to show an image. This would only happen on messages that have an image:

[image] [image]

However sometime I scroll down and scroll back up and the images just disappear like so:

[image]

And sometimes I scroll up and down on the `RecyclerView` and messages that shouldn't have an attachment have one:

[image] [image]

In my `MessageAdapter` I have two `ViewType`s, one is for the Header Message, and the other is for the Comment Messages.

This is what my `MessageAdapter` looks like:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int TYPE_MESSAGE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_MESSAGE_COMMENT = 1;

    private Context mContext;
    private Message mOriginalMessage;
    private List<Message> mMessages;

    public MessageAdapter(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void setOriginalMessage(Message originalMessage) {
    this.mOriginalMessage = originalMessage;
    }

    public void setMessages(List<Message> messages) {
        this.mMessages = new ArrayList<>(messages);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_MESSAGE_HEADER) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_header,
                parent, false);
            return new MessageViewHolder(v, viewType);
        } else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_comment,
                parent, false);
            return new MessageViewHolder(v, viewType);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final MessageViewHolder messageViewHolder = (MessageViewHolder) holder;
        int viewType = holder.getItemViewType();

        switch (viewType) {
            case TYPE_MESSAGE_HEADER:

                if (messageViewHolder.mIsViewExpanded && mOriginalMessage.getAttachment() != null)
                    animateHeader(messageViewHolder);

                // Other initialization stuff

                // Set the image
                if (mOriginalMessage.getAttachment() != null) {
                    messageViewHolder.mHeaderImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    messageViewHolder.mHeaderShowTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    messageViewHolder.mHeaderShowTextView.setText("Show Attachment");
                    String attachmentUrl = mOriginalMessage.getAttachment().getImageUrl();
                    if (messageViewHolder.mIsViewExpanded) {
                        Picasso.with(mContext)
                                .load(attachmentUrl)
                                .into(messageViewHolder.mHeaderImage);
                    }

                    messageViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            animateHeader(messageViewHolder);
                        }
                    });
                }

                break;
            case TYPE_MESSAGE_COMMENT:

                Message message = mMessage.get(position - 1);

                if (messageViewHolder.mIsViewExpanded && message.getAttachment() != null)
                    animateComment(messageViewHolder);

                // Other initialization stuff

                // Show attachment if there is an attachment
                if (message.getAttachment() != null) {
                    messageViewHolder.mMessageImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    messageViewHolder.mMessageShowTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    messageViewHolder.mMessageShowTextView.setText("Show Attachment");
                    String attachmentUrl = message.getAttachment().getImageUrl();
                    if (messageViewHolder.mIsViewExpanded) {
                        Picasso.with(mContext)
                                .load(attachmentUrl)
                                .into(messageViewHolder.mMessageImage);
                    }

                    messageViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            animateComment(messageViewHolder);
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionHeader(position)) {
            return TYPE_MESSAGE_HEADER;
        }
        return TYPE_MESSAGE_COMMENT;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }

    // GUESSING SOMETHING WRONG HERE?
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mOriginalMessage != null && mMessages != null) {
           if (!mMessages.isEmpty())
                return mMessages.size() + 1;
            else
                return 1;
        } else if (mMessages != null) {
            if (!mMessages.isEmpty())
                return mMessages.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

     private void animateHeader(final MessageViewHolder messageViewHolder) {

        if (messageViewHolder.mOriginalHeight == 0)
            messageViewHolder.mOriginalHeight = messageViewHolder.itemView.getHeight();

        ValueAnimator valueAnimator;
            if (!messageViewHolder.mIsViewExpanded) {
            messageViewHolder.mHeaderImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            messageViewHolder.mHeaderImage.setEnabled(true);
            messageViewHolder.mIsViewExpanded = true;
            valueAnimator = ValueAnimator
                .ofInt(messageViewHolder.mOriginalHeight, commentViewHolder.mOriginalHeight
                            + (int) (messageViewHolder.mOriginalHeight * 0.8) + 10);
            messageViewHolder.mHeaderShowTextView.setText("Hide Attachment");
        } else {
            messageViewHolder.mIsViewExpanded = false;
            valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(messageViewHolder.mOriginalHeight + (int) (messageViewHolder.mOriginalHeight * 0.8)
                            + 10, messageViewHolder.mOriginalHeight);
            Animation a = new AlphaAnimation(1.00f, 0.00f);

            a.setDuration(200);
            a.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    messageViewHolder.mHeaderShowTextView.setText("Show Attachment");
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    messageViewHolder.mAttachmentImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    messageViewHolder.mHeaderImage.setEnabled(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
           });

           messageViewHolder.mHeaderImage.startAnimation(a);
        }

        valueAnimator.setDuration(400);
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new BakedBezierInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                messageViewHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                messageViewHolder.itemView.requestLayout();
            }
        });

        valueAnimator.start();
    }

    private void animateComment(final MessageViewHolder messageViewHolder) {

        if (messageViewHolder.mOriginalHeight == 0)
             messageViewHolder.mOriginalHeight = messageViewHolder.itemView.getHeight();

        ValueAnimator valueAnimator;
        if (!messageViewHolder.mIsViewExpanded) {
            messageViewHolder.mMessageImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            messageViewHolder.mMessageImage.setEnabled(true);
            messageViewHolder.mIsViewExpanded = true;
            valueAnimator = ValueAnimator
                .ofInt(messageViewHolder.mOriginalHeight, messageViewHolder.mOriginalHeight
                            + (int) (messageViewHolder.mOriginalHeight * 0.8) + 10);
            messageViewHolder.mMessageShowTextView.setText("Hide Attachment");
        } else {
            messageViewHolder.mIsViewExpanded = false;
            valueAnimator = ValueAnimator
                .ofInt(messageViewHolder.mOriginalHeight + (int) (messageViewHolder.mOriginalHeight * 0.8)
                            + 10, messageViewHolder.mOriginalHeight);
            Animation a = new AlphaAnimation(1.00f, 0.00f);

            a.setDuration(200);
            a.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    messageViewHolder.mMessageShowTextView.setText("Show Attachment");
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    messageViewHolder.mMessageImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    messageViewHolder.mMessageImage.setEnabled(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });

            messageViewHolder.mMessageImage.startAnimation(a);
        }

        valueAnimator.setDuration(300);
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new BakedBezierInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                messageViewHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                messageViewHolder.itemView.requestLayout();
            }
        });

        valueAnimator.start();
    }

    public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        // Header
        private ImageView mHeaderImage;
        private TextView mHeaderShowTextView;

        // Comment
        private ImageView mMessageImage;
        private TextView mMessageShowTextView;

        // Variables for View
        private int mOriginalHeight = 0;
        private boolean mIsViewExpanded = false;

        private int mHolderId;

        public MessageViewHolder(View itemView, int viewType) {
            super(itemView);
            if (viewType == TYPE_MESSAGE_HEADER)
                initHeaderViews(itemView);
            else if (viewType == TYPE_MESSAGE_COMMENT)
                initCommentViews(itemView);
        }

        private void initHeaderViews(View view) {
            mHeaderImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.header_image);
            mHeaderShowTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.header_show_textview);
            mHeaderShowTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            if (!mIsViewExpanded) {
                mHeaderImage.setEnabled(false);
                mHeaderImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            mHolderId = TYPE_MESSAGE_HEADER;
        }

        private void initCommentViews(View view) {
            mMessageImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemAttachmentImage);
            mMessageShowTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.showItemAttachment);
            mMessageShowTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            if (!mIsViewExpanded) {
                mMessageShowTextView.setText("Show Attachment");
                mMessageImage.setEnabled(false);
                mMessageImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            mHolderId = TYPE_MESSAGE_COMMENT;
       }

    }

}
```

Is there anyway to do this better and more accurately? Specifically the biggest issue is removing any of the inconsistencies and if this code can be decoupled.

How can I get the correct messages to only show their attachments properly? How can I keep images in a card even when I scroll up or down? This also starts to get messy when I add new comments as well, because now there is an `N + 1` issue.

Specifically I am wondering if there is a better way to handle multiple `ViewHolders` rather trying to keep a handle on `offset` values for the `RecyclerView`.

**Update:**

I was able to reduce some complexity in my adapter by using the following in the `Fragment` I am initializing my `RecyclerView.Adapter` in:

```
public void setParentMessage(Message parentMessage) {
    this.mParentMessage = parentMessage;
    mAllMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    mAllMessages.add(mParentMessage);
}

public void setMessages(List<Messages> messages) {
    this.mMessages = messages;
    mAllMessages.addAll(mMessages);
}
```

Then I just initialize my adapter on start:

```
mMessageAdapter.setMessages(mAllMessages);
```

Then if I have to add a new `Message` object to my list I can simply do the following:

```
public void addComment(Message message) {
    mMessageAdapter.addItem(mMessageAdapter.getItemCount(), message);
    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mMessageAdapter.size() - 1);
}
```

Inside my `MessageAdapter` I have the following to add a new Message comment:

```
public void addItem(int position, Message message) {
    mMessages.add(position, message);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}
```

What this means is that I am able to change this:

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mOriginalMessage != null && mMessages != null) {
           if (!mMessages.isEmpty())
                return mMessages.size() + 1;
            else
                return 1;
        } else if (mMessages != null) {
            if (!mMessages.isEmpty())
                return mMessages.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

To this:

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mMessages != null) {
            if (!mMessages.isEmpty())
                return mMessages.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

And inside my `onBindViewHolder` method I do not need to keep track off offsets anymore, so this changes:

```
Message message = mMessage.get(position - 1);
```

To:

```
Message message = mMessage.get(position);
```

Furthermore I decoupled `MessageViewHolder` into two separate `ViewHolder` classes:

```
public class MessageHeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        // Header
        private ImageView mHeaderImage;
        private TextView mHeaderShowTextView;

        // Variables for View
        private int mOriginalHeight = 0;
        private boolean mIsViewExpanded = false;

        private int mHolderId;

        public MessageHeaderViewHolder(View itemView, int viewType) {
            super(itemView);
            initHeaderViews(itemView);
        }

        private void initHeaderViews(View view) {
            mHeaderImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.header_image);
            mHeaderShowTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.header_show_textview);
            mHeaderShowTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            if (!mIsViewExpanded) {
                mHeaderImage.setEnabled(false);
                mHeaderImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            mHolderId = TYPE_MESSAGE_HEADER;
        }

        private void initOnClickListener() {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    animate(v);
                }
            });
        }

        private void removeClickListener() {
            if (itemView.hasOnClickListeners())
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // THIS CODE DOESN'T WORK AS THOUGHT.
                    // Empty click listener to keep itemSelectableBackground.
                }
            });
        }

        private void animate(View v) {
            // All animation code for header moved here
        }

    }
```

Same thing for the other `ViewHolder`:

```
public class MessageCommentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        // Comment
        private ImageView mMessageImage;
        private TextView mMessageShowTextView;

        // Variables for View
        private int mOriginalHeight = 0;
        private boolean mIsViewExpanded = false;

        private int mHolderId;

        public MessageCommentViewHolder(View itemView, int viewType) {
            super(itemView);
            initCommentViews(itemView);
        }

        private void initCommentViews(View view) {
            mMessageImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemAttachmentImage);
            mMessageShowTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.showItemAttachment);
            mMessageShowTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            if (!mIsViewExpanded) {
                mMessageShowTextView.setText("Show Attachment");
                mMessageImage.setEnabled(false);
                mMessageImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            mHolderId = TYPE_MESSAGE_COMMENT;
       }

        private void initOnClickListener() {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    animate(v);
                }
            });
        }

        private void removeClickListener() {
            if (itemView.hasOnClickListeners())
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // THIS CODE DOESN'T WORK AS THOUGHT.
                    // Empty click listener to keep itemSelectableBackground.
                }
            });
        }

        private void animate(View v) {
            // All animation code for header moved here
        }

    }
```

This means that inside my `onBindViewHolder` method I can do the following for each type of item (keep in mind there will be two types of `ViewHolder`s now so `messageViewHolder` would be changed to either `headerViewHolder` or `commentViewHolder` or something similar):

```
if (message.getAttachment() != null) {
                    messageViewHolder.mMessageImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    messageViewHolder.mMessageShowTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    messageViewHolder.mMessageShowTextView.setText("Show Attachment");
                    String attachmentUrl = message.getAttachment().getImageUrl();
                    Picasso.with(mContext)
                            .load(attachmentUrl)
                            .into(messageViewHolder.mMessageImage);

                    messageViewHolder.initOnClickListener();
                } else {
                    messageViewHolder.removeClickListener();
                    messageViewHolder.mMessageImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    messageViewholder.mMessageShowTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
```

It is working fine now, although this is a very hacky solution, I plan to use doubleA's answer and make this code more optimized over this weekend. One problem that is still persisting is that some items will have `itemSelectableBackground` and be `clickable` while others are not, from my understanding `removeClickListener()` should initialize an empty `View.OnClickListener` thus making the item clickable therefore showing an `itemSelectableBackground` but this is not the case?? The `Log` output is saying I am initializing the listeners and images correctly.

Comment: Why did this get a close vote? This is a legitimate question regarding dynamic data inside a recyclerview. Please explain why you think this should be closed instead of just voting for it. Specifically I see a design implementation issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem with recycler views and was actually an interview question for me recently. When you are using the recycler view and view holders it does what it says... recycles views. So if you start scrolling down and one view has an image attached and you display that image and then a little ways down when that view is recycled and the new data you are putting into it does not have an image associated with it your code does not explicitly tell the parent viewholder to hide the image view within it. So your image is showing up on recycled views because it was already there and just recycled.

Here is my suggestion

```
if (message.getAttachment() != null) {
//all your fun view binding stuff.
} else {
    messageViewHolder.mMessageImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Also I would suggest you put the view binding code into your View holder and use 2 different view holders with the same layout if you must. It will shorten you onBindViewHolder call and links the different view binding code with the view holder associated with it. Here is an example of one of my recycler view adapters.

```
public class ProgramRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

/** 
This is an abstract class that all of my viewholders inherit from. 
This is a contract telling me that any subclasses that inherit from this
base class are required to write their own `public void bind(int position,
Program program);` method. 
*/
abstract class ProgramBaseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ProgramBaseViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public abstract void bindDataToView(int position, Program program);
}
```

I realize that the keyword bind is used multiple times in this view holder and they are doing different things. `@Bind` and Butterknife.bind is part of a viewbinding library called Butterknife made by the same nice people that provide you with Picasso. This usage of "bind" is the equivalent of your `findViewById()` calls. The abstract class' bind is just a common name for a method that binds data to views in an adapter. I have renamed bind to bindDataToView to be a little more explicit.

```
/**
This is the Airtime view that holds airtimes. It is a view holder that
inherits from my base view holder and implements its own version if bind.
*/
class AirtimeViewHolder extends ProgramBaseViewHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.program_airtimes)
    TextView mProgramAirtimes;

    static final int viewType = 0;

    public AirtimeViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        /**This call to butterknife can be replaced with an
        itemView.findViewById(R.id.yourview) */
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    //This is where you set your text and hide or show your views.
    @Override
    public void bindDataToView(int position, Program program) {
        List<Airtime> airtimes = program.getAirtimes();
        if (!airtimes.isEmpty()) {
            mProgramAirtimes.setText(Utils.getFriendlyAirtimes(airtimes));
        } else {
            mProgramAirtimes.setText(
                    Utils.getFriendlyAirTime(program.getAirtime()));
        }
    }
}

/**
This is the Description view that holds descriptions. It is a view holder  
that inherits from my base view holder and implements its own version if    
bind.
*/
class DescriptionViewHolder extends ProgramBaseViewHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.description_card_layout)
    TextView mProgramDescription;

    static final int viewType = 1;

    public DescriptionViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindDataToView(int position, Program program) {
        mProgramDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml(program.getFullDescription()));
    }
}
//This is another type of view with another different type of layout.
class HostsViewHolder extends ProgramBaseViewHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.card_view_host_name)
    TextView mProgramHostName;

    static final int viewType = 2;

    public HostsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindDataToView(int position, Program program) {
        mProgramHostName.setText(program.getHosts().get(position - 2).getDisplayName());
    }
}
//Again another type of view extending my base view.
class CategoriesViewHolder extends ProgramBaseViewHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.program_categories)
    TextView mProgramCategories;
    static final int viewType = 42;

    public CategoriesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindDataToView(int position, Program program) {
        List<Category> categoryList = program.getCategories();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Category category : categoryList) {
            stringBuilder.append(category.getTitle())
                    .append(" ");
        }
        mProgramCategories.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
}

//This is where the normal looking recycler view code comes in.
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Program mProgramData;
private int mNextProgramId;

public ProgramRecyclerAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
}

/**This method is where I am determining what view type each item in my list 
will be. I wanted a single airtimes view followed by a single description 
view and then X amount of hosts views and a single category view. I return 
position in the third else if because the position helps me determine which 
host name to display in the bindDataToViews call of the HostViewHolder.*/
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == AirtimeViewHolder.viewType) {
        return AirtimeViewHolder.viewType;
    } else if (position == DescriptionViewHolder.viewType) {
        return DescriptionViewHolder.viewType;
    } else if (position > DescriptionViewHolder.viewType
            && position <= DescriptionViewHolder.viewType + getHostsNum()) {
        return position;
    } else {
        return CategoriesViewHolder.viewType;
    }
}

//This method figures out how many hosts will be displayed
private int getHostsNum() {
    if (mProgramData != null) {
        return mProgramData.getHosts().size();
    }
    return 0;
}
// This method determines if I will show a category view or not.
private int getCategoriesNum() {
    if (mProgramData != null && mProgramData.getCategories().size() > 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

/**This returns haw many items will be in the list. 1 Airtime view, 1 
Description view, x amount of Host views and 0 or 1 category views */
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 2 + getHostsNum() + getCategoriesNum();
}

/** This returns the appropriate View holder for the requested view type that 
was set by getItemViewType(). I pass the inflated parent view and the data.     
*/
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == AirtimeViewHolder.viewType) {
        return new AirtimeViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.airtime_card_layout, parent, false));
    } else if (viewType == DescriptionViewHolder.viewType) {
        return new DescriptionViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.description_card_layout, parent, false));
    } else if (viewType > DescriptionViewHolder.viewType
            && viewType <= DescriptionViewHolder.viewType + getHostsNum()) {
        return new HostsViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.hosts_card_layout, parent, false));
    } else
        return new CategoriesViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_card_layout, parent, false));
}

/*This method is what ties everything together. After I ensure that the data 
is not null I call bindDataToView on a ProgramBaseViewHolder. Depending on 
which type of subclass it is will determine which overridden bindData code to 
use. */
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ProgramBaseViewHolder baseViewHolder = (ProgramBaseViewHolder) holder;
    if (mProgramData != null) {
        baseViewHolder.bindDataToView(position, mProgramData);
    }
}

//This is used to set the data for this program
public void setProgramData(Program program) {
    mProgramData = program;
}

public Program getProgramData() {
    return mProgramData;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return mProgramData == null;
}
}
```

This is the Airtime layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">  
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"> 
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/airtimes_label"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/> 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/program_airtimes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />  
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my host layout. You will notice that I am not using most of the views here because this is an app in progress.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/host_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/host_image"
            android:layout_width="112dp"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/details"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/host_image"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/card_view_host_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
                android:layout_gravity="left" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/card_view_hosts_programs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image: This is the view that is produced with some data. The Categories view is cut off but it is there.]

Comment: could you separate each of the methods inside your RecyclerView.Adapter class and describe each method accordingly? I think that would help out a lot of people including me.

Comment: @AndyRoid I added comments, images and some more code. I hope that helps.

Comment: This is very thought out and thorough doubleA, I almost have a fix for the bugs I am experiencing. Once I've understood your code and have it implemented, I will accept this as an answer. doubleA do you any ideas ideas why mHeaderShowTextView and mMessageShowTextView show up on items that shouldn't have an attachment to begin with? I've tried moving the onClickListener code around to the ViewHolder and only initializing it if the message has an attachment but it seems to get initialized regardless on some items which is very strange.

Comment: Nice job doubleA, this post will help out a lot of people. Although I haven't completely got a fix for my issues, I felt this was a thorough answer and you came back to add comments.

Comment: You should edit your post with updated code if it has changed. Did you solve the problem of image views where there shouldnt be with my first fix? I am guessing that the same issue is occuring on your other views. If the data is there then you set them. If the data is not there and your adapter is filling a recycled view then it will still have the content from the previous data.

Comment: And yes your first suggestion helped, very simple solution I overlooked in my adapter code! `Update:` I like your second suggestion as well of binding data in the `ViewHolder`.